# SetInterval ejecuta todas las funciones

Tags: javascript, firebase

Cuando intento una ejecutar una funcion con SetInterval cada X tiempo se ejecutan todas. El código esta en JavaScript. Tambien he intentado poner el setInterval y después poner toda la función directamente pero tampoco funciona. Este es mi código, en principio el setInterval solo tendria que ejecutar miraralarma pero me encuentro con que ejecuta todas las funciones que tengo. Todo esto esta en el cloud functions de firebase.
El tornaposicio solo tiene que escribir en la base de datos, enviar una notificación y devolver un vector.
El esborrarllista solo tiene que borrar de la base de datos y luego enviar una notificación.
Mirar alarma se tendria que ejecutar cada 30 segundos para restar tiempo a un temporizador.

```
async function miraralarma(){
  var tokenstosend = [];
  var refsnapshot = await database.ref("Usuaris").once('value');
  console.log("He entrat a la funcio");
  if (refsnapshot.hasChildren()) {
    refsnapshot.forEach(function(childs) {
      if (childs.hasChild("alarma")){
        var alarmvalue =childs.val().alarma;
        if(alarmvalue != (-1)) {
          var alarmref = database.ref("Usuaris/" + childs.key);
          if ((alarmvalue-15000) < 0 || (alarmvalue-15000) === 0) {
            var id = childs.key;
            if (childs.hasChild("ubicacio")){
              var Long = childs.val().ubicacio.longitud;
              var Lat = childs.val().ubicacio.latitud;
              tokenstosend = comprovaraprop(id, refsnapshot, Long, Lat);
              var personaperill = childs.val().nom;
              if (tokenstosend.length>0) {
                enviarnotialarm(tokenstosend, personaperill);
              }
            }
            alarmref.update({
              alarma: -1,
            });
          }
          else {
            alarmref.update({
              alarma: (alarmvalue-15000),
            });
          }
        }
      }   
    });
  }
}

exports.tornaposicio = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onCall(async(data, context) => {
    // Message text passed from the client.
    if (!(data instanceof Object)) {
        // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'The function must be called with ' +
            'a object');
    }
    // Checking that the user is authenticated.
    if (!context.auth) {
        // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called ' +
            'while authenticated.');
    }

    const Long = data['longitud'];
    const Lat = data['latitud'];
    var enperilluid = [];
    var retornartots = [];
    console.log("He entrat a tornaposicio")
    // Authentication / user information is automatically added to the request.
    const userid = context.auth.uid;
    var refuser = await database.ref('Usuaris/' + userid).once('value');
    var personaperill = refuser.val().nom;
    var vectoraprop = [];
    var tokens = [];
    var d;
    var snapshot = await database.ref("Usuaris").once('value');
    var trobat = 0;
    var pues1 = database.ref('Usuaris/' + userid + '/uids');
    pont1 = await pues1.once('value');
    pont1.forEach(function (child23){
      enperilluid.push(child23.val());
      retornartots.push(child23.val());
    });
    console.log(enperilluid);
    if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
            snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
              if (childSnapshot.hasChild("ubicacio")){
                var id = childSnapshot.key;
                var lati = childSnapshot.val().ubicacio.latitud;
                var longi = childSnapshot.val().ubicacio.longitud;
                d = calcularposicio(Long, Lat, lati, longi)
                if (d <= llunyaniames || d >= llunyaniamenys) {
                  if(enperilluid.length > 0) {
                    for (var i=0; i<enperilluid.length; ++i) {
                      trobat = 0;
                      if (enperilluid[i] == childSnapshot.key){
                        trobat = 1;
                        break;
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  if (trobat == 0) {
                    vectoraprop.push(id);
                    pues1.push(id);
                    retornartots.push(id);
                    //Posa els tokens dels que estan aprop
                    if (childSnapshot.hasChild("notificationtoken")){
                      tokens.push(childSnapshot.val().notificationtoken);
                      enviarnotiajuda(childSnapshot.val().notificationtoken, userid, personaperill, d);
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            });
    }
    return retornartots;
});

exports.esborrarllista = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onCall(async(data, context) => {
  if (!(data instanceof Object)) {
    // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'The function must be called with ' +
        'a object');
}
  if (!context.auth) {
    // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
  //  throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called ' +
  //      'while authenticated.');
  }
  console.log("He entrat a esborrarllista");
  var idusuari = context.auth.uid;
  var tokenarray = [];
  var uidarray = [];
  var nombreintent = await database.ref('/Usuaris/' + idusuari).once('value');
  var personaperill = nombreintent.val().nom;
  var uidsref = database.ref('/Usuaris/' + idusuari + '/uids');
  var snapshotuids = await uidsref.once('value');
  var fref = [];

  snapshotuids.forEach(function (child23){
    uidarray.push(child23.val());
  });
  console.log(uidarray);

  for (uid of uidarray){
    fref= await database.ref('/Usuaris/' + uid + '/notificationtoken').once('value');
    tokenarray.push(fref.val());
  }
  await uidsref.remove();
  console.log("Ha esborrat uids i ara enviara " +tokenarray.length + " notificacions")
  if(tokenarray.length > 0) {
    enviarnoticancel(tokenarray, personaperill);
  }
});

setInterval(miraralarma, 30000);
```

Comment: Buenas  Marc, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, traduce la pregunta ya que el español es el unico idioma oficial aqui. Además, aclara el problema siguiendo [ask] y [mcve]. Mira el [tour] para más info. Un saludo!

Comment: Sigue sin entenderse muy bien la pregunta, hay más funciones además de `miraralarma` que se estén ejecutando?
Con `setInterval` como está ahora va a ejecutarse `miraralarma` cada 30 segundos y todas las que estén dentro de `miraralarma`

Comment: @ramirozap En principio solo se tendria que ejecutar mirar alarma, ademas de la comprovaraprop y enviarnotialarma. Pero se ejecutan todas las funciones que tengo declaradas aunque no esten dentro de miraralarma

Comment: @MarcIglesias no veo nada extraño en el archivo, seguramente se me esté pasando algo, a lo mejor alguien más puede ayudarte.